# What data structure to use for screen splitting like in Blender?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, 2d, blender

If you have ever used Blender, you know how a screen splitting works there. Basically you can always split screen vertically down or horizontally left and merge in reverse order iff screens fully share an edge.

I want to implement this kind of feature and tried several approaches. The most promising approach was to use a binary tree in a recursive manner like thinking of every node as a screen. Those that are already splitted have, for example, a string value showing a "split type (horizontal or vertical)" in internal nodes and actual children screens at leaves. An adjusted traversal and screen size information in nodes allowed me to determine whether one screen has mergable neighbor (not only sibling). But as it turned out there are such configurations that the binary tree cannot represent.

In general what kind of data structure does Blender use for splitting 2d area into rectangular chunks? In particular, how did they solve this problem?

Example of impossible configuration

1. Before merging

   ```
    ______________
   |         |  c |
   |_________|____|
   |  |      |  d |
   |  |______|____|
   |__|__|_a_|__b_|
   ```
2. After merging **a** -> **b**

   ```
    ______________
   |         |  c |
   |_________|____|
   |  |      |  d |
   |  |______|____|
   |__|__|________|
   ```
3. After merging **d** -> **c**

   ```
    ______________
   |         |    |
   |_________|    |
   |  |      |    |
   |  |______|____|
   |__|__|________|
   ```

There is no edge that cuts screen in half.

Comment: A data structure is supposed to help with some specific access pattern (while likely slowing down patterns it is not fit for). Your needs seems to be "find split candidates" (harder part - you need to check all blocks aligned with selected line, not just adjacent) and "find join candidates" - with known direction (horizontal/vertical) in both cases. It can be accelerated with two arrays sorted by edge offset from origin point - one for each direction; but I honestly think it is overkill as number of elements will never be high - so, just flat array.